# A specific question about Sudoku

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Recent research within the sudoku community concerns impossible arrangements of a single or multiple digits. This is a broad topic, but the following specific question has gained some importance:

Let's restrict ourselves to 9x9 sudoku with standard rules: each digit 1-9 must appear once in every row, column and marked 3x3 box of the grid.

- A *k-rookery* is a subset of the 81 cells containing exactly k cells from each row, column and box.
- A *k-template* is a k-rookery whose 9k cells are filled with numbers from {1,2,..,k},
  such that the rookery-cells from each row,column and box contain each digit from {1,..,k}
  exactly once.

Some k-rookeries contain k-templates, some k-rookeries do not contain templates at all.
Let's restrict ourselves further to 3-rookeries, such that the three cells within each 3x3 box span all three rows and columns (sometimes called an "*open*" configuration).

We are interested in the question whether such an open 3-rookery contains a 1-template - in other words: Is it possible to place 9 instances of a digit within these cells?
For most of these, this can be answered with (some symmetry transformation, aka "morph" followed by) a "modulo 3 test":

If $r_i$ and $c_i$ are the row- and column-numbers of the 9 instances of some digit $d$ with $r_i, c_i \in\{0,\ldots,8\}$ for $i \in\{0,\ldots,8\}$, then

$$
\sum_{i=0}^{8}(r_i+c_i)=\sum_{i=0}^{8}r_i + \sum_{i=0}^{8}c_i= 72\equiv 0\pmod3 
$$

So the diagonals fall in three modulo-classes {-1,0,1}, which - given the arrangements of 8 of the 9 3x3 boxes - allows to determine the one arrangement of the 9th box, such that a 1-template can exist.
It turns out this is not sufficient though. The following open 3-rookery does not have a 1-template, but passes the modulo 3 test:

[image: 3-rookery without 1-template (image)]

[Link to puzzle in a solving/setting-software](https://f-puzzles.com/?id=2qd6mazf)

It is of course possible to prove that no digit can be filled in 9 times within the unshaded cells of this pattern, but all known proofs using classic sudoku techniques (such as skyskrapers) require consideration of multiple cases and are rather unsatisfying.

Questions:

- What would be a standard way of stating such a problem mathematically at all? I have failed so far so view it as some graph-coloring problem.
- Is there by any chance some quick way to see that these cells are not "fillable" by a single digit at a glance? Some modified version of above "modulo-test" maybe?

Comment: There is some terminology for these things in terms of hypergraphs, but I'm not sure that the hypergraph people have any insight to add.